# How do I use a button in a windows API program

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make a button and something to happen when I click it. I used a while loop to make the button, but I am trying to make something happen when I click it. I am using c++ console application.

```
#define VK_LBUTTON 0x01
#define VK_RBUTTON 0x02
#include <Windows.h>
#include "tchar.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MSG msg;
    //if you add WS_CHILD flag,CreateWindow will fail because there is no parent window.
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("button"), TEXT("Easy"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_POPUP,
        500, 500, 80, 25, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: You have to add a window procedure, add a window, then add a button with `WS_CHILD` style within that window. If using Visual Studio, it can automatically create a Window hello world program. Otherwise see this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

A [`BUTTON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/buttons) control needs a parent window, but you are not creating one. And that parent window needs a window procedure to handle messages sent to it. When a button is clicked, it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notification to its parent window. Your message loop will never see it.